# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error in this code -> responseData{ (response) in

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

i am using this code for download video and it will give me an error the code is given below

```
let videoImageUrl = "my_video_link"
        AF.request(videoImageUrl).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
//            print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            
        }).responseData { (response) in
            
//        }
        
            if let data = response.result.value {

                // my code
            }
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, I don't know which version of Alamofire you're using (since there might have been changes), but `response` is a `AFDataResponse<Data>`, so it's then `if let data = response.data` or `switch response.result { case .success(let data): break case .failure(let error): break }`

Comment: @Larme pod of Alamofire is Alamofire (5.8.1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `response.result` is `Result<Data, AFError>`, and it doesn't have the `value` property. You can do it this way:

```swift
if let data = try? response.result.get() {
    //TODO: do something with data          
}

do {
    let data = try response.result.get()
    //TODO: do something with data
} catch {
    //Catch error here
}
```

Or

```swift
switch response.result {
case .success(let data):
    break
case .failure(let error):
    break
}
```